# Who can give a errorformat of vim for android making output

Tags: android, vim, editor

When i compile a android module from Android Open Source Project using mm, the output is as follow:

> ============================================ PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.5
>   TARGET_PRODUCT=generic TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng TARGET_SIMULATOR=
>   TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release TARGET_BUILD_APPS= TARGET_ARCH=arm
>   HOST_ARCH=x86 HOST_OS=linux HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release BUILD_ID=GRJ90
>   ============================================ make: Entering directory `/home/ccheng/gs_android' target Java: Contacts
>   (out/target/common/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/classes)
>   GroupEditActivity.java:46: not a statement   aa}
>   GroupEditActivity.java:46: ';' expected   aa}
>
> 2 errors make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar]
>   Error 41 make: Leaving directory `/home/ccheng/gs_android'

And my editor is vim, and make in vim using `:make`. Can any one can give a suitable 'errorformat' for this error?
thanks.

Comment: I am not here to ask for where the error is. I am trying to find a way to let vim locate the error line.

Comment: The output is exactly as displayed on your question? The first line really include all the information about the plataform, informs that make changed the current directory and informs about the first error? Or there are multiple lines and they are just incorrectly displayed here?

Comment: Maybe this publication will help you: http://goo.gl/0GFbG  it's about Android development using Vim with plugin Eclim. I found it very useful. You don't need to care about errorformat, Eclim provides command :ProjectProblems which shows you all errors in proper format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. It's because the quote around the error message is not both `''` but `` `' ``. I am not quite understand why google output error in this way.

Comment: ok, so you solved your problem, how about sharing the whole solution instead of just a hint. E.g. what was/How did you use the error format?

Comment: here is my error format. `set efm=%Dmake:\ Entering\ directory\ `%f',%f:%l:%m,%Xmake:\ Leaving\ directory\ `%f'`. If you still have any question, just comment below.

Comment: @FrankCheng: It would be nice if you add your comment into your answer, so that it can be seen directly and the format is readable while in the comment it is definitly not. Thanks!